# GCP Dataproc parallel steps execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am creating dataproc cluster on GCP using a workflow template from YAML files. Once the cluster is created all the steps start executing in parallel but I want some steps to execute after all other steps have completed execution. is there any way to achieve this?

sample YAML used for cluster creation

```
jobs:
- pigJob:
    continueOnFailure: true
    queryList:
      queries:
      - sh /ui.sh
  stepId: run-pig-ui
- pigJob:
    continueOnFailure: true
    queryList:
      queries:
      - sh /hotel.sh
  stepId: run-pig-hotel

placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: cluster-abc
    labels:
      data: cluster
    config:
      configBucket: bucket-1
      initializationActions:
        - executableFile: gs://bucket-1/install_git.sh
          executionTimeout: 600s
      gceClusterConfig:
        zoneUri: asia-south1-a
        tags:
          - test
      masterConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-8
        diskConfig:
          bootDiskSizeGb: 50
      workerConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-highcpu-32
        numInstances: 2
        diskConfig:
          bootDiskSizeGb: 100
      softwareConfig:
        imageVersion: 1.4-ubuntu18
        properties:
          core:io.compression.codec.lzo.class: com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec
          core:io.compression.codecs: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
      secondaryWorkerConfig:
        numInstances: 2
        isPreemptible: true
```

the command used to create the cluster

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate-from-file --file file_name.yaml
```

gcloud version: 261.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `prerequisiteStepIds` list in your final workflow step to make sure it only runs after all your prerequisite steps have run. You can see the expected structure in the [corresponding JSON API representation for OrderedJob](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflowTemplates#orderedjob).

```
jobs:
- pigJob:
    continueOnFailure: true
    queryList:
      queries:
      - sh /ui.sh
  stepId: run-pig-ui
- pigJob:
    continueOnFailure: true
    queryList:
      queries:
      - sh /hotel.sh
  stepId: run-pig-hotel
- pigJob:
    continueOnFailure: true
    queryList:
      queries:
      - sh /final.sh
  stepId: run-final-step
  prerequisiteStepIds:
    - run-pig-ui
    - run-pig-hotel
...
```